# Is there a way to easily put all elements between 2 indexes into a nestled list in Python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, indexing, curly-braces

I have a list l

```py
l = ['a','a','{','b','a','{','a','}','}','a']
```

I want to turn this list into the list below.

```py
print(new_l)
# ['a','a',['{','b','a',['{','a','}'],'}'],'a']
```

So, basically, everything inside curly braces, including the bracces themselves should be inside a list nestled inside the original list.

Edit: Thank you all for the wonderful answers. Now, what I want the nestled lists to include the element before '{' as well? I know I should have mentioned this initially, but forgot about this requirement.

```py
print(new_l)
# ['a',['a','{','b',['a','{','a','}'],'}'],'a']
```

Comment: Easily? I don't so.. You'd have to use a stack, keep pushing indices where you see `'{'`, and when you encounter a closing brace, you'd replace all the elements between two indices with a list.. You'd also need to offset each index in the stack with the count of elements deleted so far.. If you can show us your existing attempt at solving this, we can perhaps help you..

Comment: what can be a element of list ? only alphabets ?

Comment: Recursion will work here - replacing all bounded indexes between '{' and '}' with a list including those elements until no more brackets are found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```py
import json

def add_nested_lists(l):
    ltemp = '['
    last_element = ''
    n = len(l)
    for i in range(0, n):
        element = l[i]
        if element == '{':
            if l[i-1] == "{":
                last_element = '"{", '
                ltemp = ltemp[0:len(ltemp) - len(last_element)]
                ltemp += '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
                last_element = '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
            else:
                ltemp = ltemp[0:len(ltemp) - len(last_element)]
                ltemp += '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
                last_element = '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
        elif element == "}": 
            if i == n - 1:
                ltemp += '"' + element + '"]' + ']'
                last_element = '"' + element + '"]' + ']'
            else:
                ltemp += '"' + element + '"]' + ', '
                last_element = '"' + element + '"]' + ', '
            
        else:
            if i == 0 or i != n - 1:  # first element or  middle elements
                ltemp += '"' + element + '", ' 
                last_element = '"' + element + '", ' 
            elif i == n - 1:  # last element
                ltemp += '"' + element + '"]'
                last_element = '"' + element + '"]'
    print(ltemp)
    ltemp = json.loads(ltemp)
    return ltemp

l = ['a','a','{','{','b','a','{','a','}','}','a','}']
print(type(l), add_nested_lists(l))
```

Output

```py
<class 'list'> ['a', ['a', ['{', '{', 'b', ['a', '{', 'a', '}'], '}'], 'a', '}']]
```

And if you can and want more efficiency then try to make string instead of list 'l'
as following

```py
import json

l = '['

last_element = ''
is_last_element_is_curly = False
def add(element, position='m'):  # m - middle element
    global l, last_element, is_last_element_is_curly
    if element == '{':
        if is_last_element_is_curly:
            last_element = '"{", '
            l = l[0:len(l) - len(last_element)]
            l += '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
            last_element = '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
        else:
            l = l[0:len(l) - len(last_element)]
            l += '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
            last_element = '[' + last_element + '"' + element + '", ' 
        is_last_element_is_curly = True
    elif element == "}": 
        if position == 'l':
            l += '"' + element + '"]' + ']'
            last_element = '"' + element + '"]' + ']'
        else:
            l += '"' + element + '"]' + ', '
            last_element = '"' + element + '"]' + ', '
        is_last_element_is_curly = False
    else:
        if position == 'f' or position == 'm':  # f - first element or  m - middle element
            postfix = '", '
            l += '"' + element + '", '
            last_element = '"' + element + '", '
        elif position == 'l':  # l - last element
            l += '"' + element + '"]'
            last_element = '"' + element + '"]'
        is_last_element_is_curly = False

#Do you stuff here and add elements to string 'l'
ltemp = ['a','a','{','{','b','a','{','a','}','}','a','}']
add(ltemp[0], position="f")
for i in range(1,len(ltemp) - 1):
    add(ltemp[i])
add(ltemp[i + 1], position="l")
print(l)

#After that it will become very efficient
l = json.loads(l)
print(type(l),l)
```

Comment: Oh man, that's a great hack! Didn't even occur to me to use `json`. +1

Comment: Yes, there are so many things that can be done by using json and json strings very efficiently.

Comment: Very clever use of the `json` module. Will def. be keeping this in the back of my mind going on forward.

Comment: Apologies for the addition to the question. Could you look thru it again?

Comment: if `l = [a,a,{,{,a,b,},c,},a]` then it should be converted into `[a,[a,[{,{,a,b,},],c,}],a]` am i right ?

Comment: @VoidProgrammer Now my solution is finally completed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't tried it yet, but I looked through the code and it should work! You've been a great help

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`pyparsing`](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing).

```py
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

l = ['a','a','{','b','a','{','a','}','}','a']
l.insert(0, "{")
l.insert(len(l), "}")

print(nestedExpr('{','}').parseString(" ".join(l)).asList())
```

Will output:

```
[['a', 'a', ['b', 'a', ['a']], 'a']]
```

Which is not the exact output you are looking for, but perhaps a start. From here you can just access each nested list and add `{` and `}` to them.

Comment: A bit of cheating considering it's a PyPi library, but hey, what can you do, right? ;)

Comment: Apologies for the addition to the question. Could you look thru it again?

Comment: I would open a new question if I were you. This new addition changes the question almost completely.

Comment: I was going to do so, but @Navpreet Devpuri answer my edited question. Props and Kudos to him, and to you for answering my initial question. Your solution would have worked if not for my last requirement. Thank you.